# How can I explicitly mention NONE in a particular column value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The following query :

```
SELECT e.ename , e.empno, m.ename as manager
FROM emp e LEFT OUTER JOIN emp m 
ON e.mgr = m.empno;
```

is listing employee name, employee number and their manager and also listing those employees not having 
any manager. In my case President doesn't have any manager. I want to mentione NONE in the manager column
in case of President employee as he doesn't have any manager. How can I achieve this in above query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `null` with `none` using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT e.ename, 
  e.empno, 
  coalesce(m.ename, 'none') as manager
FROM emp e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN emp m 
  ON e.mgr = m.empno;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77c49/1)

Comment: +1 because correct, but also because of fiddle and sane formatting (although I would have put the 1st column on a new line)